How to prevent Latex from adding an empty page prior to a footnotesized subsection?
I am trying to list a pretty big table of probabilities on my appendix. For it to fit, i needed \footnotesize, which barely does the job. However now there is an extra page being created between the two appendices. Originally, i thought shortening the lstlisting does the job, but it doesnt - the problem seems to stem from the page after, hence Appendix B.
Here is the code-snip i used (unsure what is relevant to it so i am probably pasting more preamble than nessecary):
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[arrow, matrix, curve]{xy}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\geometry{a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm}

\lstset{
  language=R,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  commentstyle=\color{teal},
 % keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  keepspaces=true,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2
}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{%
  \fontsize{11}{13}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont
}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3.5ex}

\addtokomafont{section}{\Huge}
\addtokomafont{section}{\textrm}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\LARGE}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\textrm}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\textrm}

\begin{document}

...
fwrite(dat_w, "C:/dat_w.csv")
\end{lstlisting}
\footnotesize
\subsection[Appendix B]{Appendix B \textmd{\footnotesize{(Probabilities being displayed in per mille)}}}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrlllllr}
\toprule
 x &   $q_{ad}(x)$ &    $q_{ai}(x)$ &    $q_{aa}(x)$ &   $q_{ii|k<1}(x)$ &  $q_{ii|k=1}(x)$ &  $q_{ii|k=2}(x)$ &  $q_{ii|k=3}(x)$  &  $q_{ii|k=4}(x)$  &  $q_{ii|k\geq 5}(x)$  \\
\midrule

...

This results in 
I have tried playing around with braces after \footnotesize, \newpage, but my Latex knowledge was hitting its limit pretty fast,as a probably overfull page wasnt expcted by me to create an empty page before it, if anything i was expecting to have the empty page after it.
Then i have tried \longtable, which is floating and therefore helps, but creates a second page for the table: 
This obviously looks somewhat better, but i would still prefer it being on one page as in the case with using \tabular.
I am thankful for any kind of help! (i know there are some roughly similar questions asked, ive looked through them and however could not really fix my problem)

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78661155

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i was under impression it got deleted there because my reviewer moved it to off-topic and told me to report here

No, I think you need to delete it yourself or it will automatically get posted after some time (unless more reviewers will spend their free time on looking at a question which has already been cross-posted.)

your tabular is too large and so tex tries to place it (and the subsection above it) on the next page before giving up and complaining about an overfull vbox. You can try \enlargethispage{2cm} to enlarge the page.

I reviewed on SO and forwarded OP here. I have literally no idea if or when the question on SO's staging ground will be closed/deleted/whatever. SO's help says nothing about it. Deleting it manually seems like a sensible suggestion.

@UlrikeFischer thank you! what an easy fix :D

@Friedrich will do that now.
